# Issue when a Python in a docker script connects to a SQL server in a stack

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-swarm, docker-network, docker-stack

I have a stack in a swarm that works well on its own (at least I think it does...). It has a postgresql working on port 5432 and a web server on port 80. The web server can properly be accessed from the outside.

For unit tests, I run only the database side, in a stack mode:

```
version: "3"
services:
  sql:
    image: sql
    networks:
    - service_network
    ports:
    - 5432:5432
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    volumes:
    - ./local_storage_sql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
    # provide your credentials here
    - POSTGRES_USER=xxxx
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxx

networks:
  service_network:
```

Then, the unit tests starts by connecting to the db in another simple python container:

```
FROM python:latest

LABEL version="0.1.0"
LABEL org.sgnn7.name="unittest"

# Make sure we are fully up to date
RUN apt-get update -q && \
  apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
  apt-get clean && \
  apt-get autoclean

RUN python -m pip install psycopg2-binary

RUN mkdir /testing

COPY ./*.py /testing/
```

The test script fail when connecting:

```
conn = connect(dbname=database, user=user, host=host, password=password)
```

with:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

But it only fails when I run it inside the container. From outside, it works like a charm. I also tried setting up an external network and use it (same docker node):

```
docker run --rm --net service_network -t UnitTest-image py.test /testing
```

Obviously, I would have expected to be more difficult to access the database from the outside of the network, than from inside, so obviously, I missed something here, but I don't know what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy a stack with Compose file, the full name of the network is created by combining the stack name with the base network name. So, let's say you deployed your stack with the name `foo` like so.

```
docker stack deploy -c compose-file.yml foo
```

Then, the full network name will be `foo_service_network`.

When you run your Python container, you need to connect it to `foo_service_network`, not `service_network`.

```
docker container run --rm --net foo_service_network -t UnitTest-image py.test /testing
```

You can also customize the network name by specifying the [name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#name-1) property in your Compose file (version 3.5 and up).

```
networks:
  service_network:
    name: service_network
```

In which case, you would connect your container to the network with that custom name.

```
docker container run --rm --net service_network -t UnitTest-image py.test /testing
```

Edit 1/28: Added Compose file example.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  sql:
    image: sql
    networks:
    - service_network
    ports:
    - 5432:5432
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    volumes:
    - ./local_storage_sql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
    # provide your credentials here
    - POSTGRES_USER=xxxx
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxx

networks:
  service_network:
    name: service_network
    attachable: true
```

Comment: If the network is created this way, it's not attachable. Already tried this.

Comment: To make it attachable, specify [`attachable: true`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#attachable).

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried all that already. If it worked, then the external network would have worked as well.

Comment: Reading between the lines on your comments, it feels like you manually created an attachable network named `service_network` at some point, and then tried to reference that in your Compose file. When you did so, did you specify [`external: true`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external-1) for it? If not, you'd end up with two different networks: one that you manually created, and another one created when you deployed the Compose file as a stack.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an edit on your Compose file. To be sure, can you try removing your deployed stack, pruning your containers and networks (`docker container prune` and `docker network prune`), and then deploying it and running your Python container?

Comment: Yes, I used `external:true`, but didn't help. I cannot connect to the stack from another docker instance, even if it uses the same network, which makes no sense :(

Comment: Still the same problem: `attachable Additional property attachable is not allowed`.

Comment: Note the `version: "3.7"` in the example Compose file. You had `"3"` in your original post, which lacks support for the `attachable` property.

Comment: `--net host` disables network namespaces, and runs your container in the name network namespace as the host.

Comment: That's what I thought for the network and probably why it worked. Still confusing. The networking in docker is not very intuitive. Also Version 3.7 is not supported on my Mint 18 Linux :/

Comment: Compose file version 3.5 is good enough for what you're trying to do here. Maybe give that a try on your system.

Comment: Even 3.5 is not OK (I have docker 17.05, I'll check if I can upgrade it).

Comment: OK, upgraded, can use 3.5, but still not able to connect when using the same network /

Comment: It feels like you just have a simple error in your network references somewhere. If you're up for a screenshare, I'm sure we could figure this out in 5 minutes.

Comment: I think it was a combination of things: what you said about the attachable and the upgrade of docker and then now I have to connect to the proper "host", which is `sql`, and not `localhost`.

Comment: Great, glad you got it figured out!

Comment: Well, it's not perfect, it still fails, but intermittently, so a different issue ;)